# How can I start a secret chat on Telegram Desktop?

Tags: linux, encryption, telegram-messenger

I know how to start a secret chat with someone using Telegram on my mobile device. But - using the Linux [desktop client](https://desktop.telegram.org/), I can't find an option for doing that. Does it exist?

Comment: There are several versions for different OSes? Which one are you using?

Comment: @ChanganAuto: Oh, sorry, I thought the client was cross-platform... amended the question.

Comment: See also the [marcovelon Telegram Desktop fork](https://github.com/marcovelon/tdesktop) that was created with the purpose of [implementing telegram secret chats on desktop](https://github.com/marcovelon/tdesktop/issues/2)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is no "Secret Chat" available in the official desktop edition of Telegram.

Saying "no" is somewhat difficult, I don't know any current official straightforward statement of Telegram about this question. Therefore the indirect prove is required:

1. In 2015 they denied thinking about integrating it ([see here](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues/118#issuecomment-72011592)). The discussion has been closed in 2016 without a positive statement.
2. The change log of the Telegram Desktop Client reaches beyond 2015 and does not even contain the word "secret". ([changelog.txt @gitub](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/dev/changelog.txt))
3. The "Secret Chat" is a significant feature that surely would be mentioned in the change log. — The absence in the change log denies its presence.

So no, unfortunately the feature hasn't been delivered until today.

There are unofficial third-party tools out there like [telegram-cli](https://github.com/vysheng/tg) or a [pidgin plugin](https://github.com/majn/telegram-purple) (unmaintained), that offer the "Secret Chat" feature. (see also the [app list at Telegram](https://telegram.org/apps))

To get the "Secret Chat" feature on the desktop is possible, but you have to trust third-party developers.